# Use closure to purify a function which builds an object through recursion — JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, closures, pure-function

I've made a promise based function which crawls up a hierarchy until it reaches the top, and resolves with an object containing the structure. My only gripe with the code is that I modify variables outside the function body, meaning that it is not a pure function. I've looked into JavaScript closures, and I fully grasp trivial uses of them. But I'm struggling to figure out how/if they can help make my function pure. My attempts at making a closure so far have only overwritten the variables, not modified them. Here is the code in question using global variables:

```
/* I want to move these variables inside function body to purify 'getPriorRows'*/
let priorRows = {}, level = 0;

const getPriorRows = id => new Promise(resolve => {
  fetch(`/api/org/${id}`).then(result => {

    /* global varaiables are modified here */
    priorRows[level++] = result;

    if (result.parentID) resolve(getPriorRows(result.parentID));
    else resolve(priorRows);

  });
});

getPriorRows('123432').then(result => console.log(result));
```

Any input on the matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're inclined to downvote, please explain why, so I can learn how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the values as arguments:

```
function getPriorRows(id, priorRows = {}, level = 0) {
  return fetch(`/api/org/${id}`).then(result => {
    /* global varaiables are modified here */
    priorRows[level] = result;

    if (result.parentID) return getPriorRows(result.parentID, priorRows, level+1);
    else return priorRows;
  });
}

getPriorRows('123432').then(result => console.log(result));
```

You can use either default parameters or a wrapper function, you don't even need a closure:

```
function getAll(id) { return getPriorRows(id, {}, 0); }
```

Also the I removed the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it).

Comment: Were you an Erlang programmer in an earlier life? ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak Not to my knowledge… I'm doing some Haskell from time to time, though.

Comment: Ah, close enough.   Using a function with one arity for the "public" interface that then calls the same-named function but with a different arity (with the additional "state" parameters) is a fairly common pattern in Erlang.

Comment: @Alnitak auxiliary/helper functions with added state variables is a common pattern in many languages

Comment: Thank you so much. This was a very elegant solution. This approach will spare me a couple lines compared to a wrapped function. Also, thanks a lot for the heads-up about abuse of promise constructors, perfect for an async beginner like myself.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to enclose the entire function and its "external" variables in a new function:

```
function getPriorRows(id) {

  let priorRows = {}, level = 0;
  const getNext = id => new Promise(
     ...
  );

  return getNext(id);
}
```

That said, your creation of an explicit `new Promise` in each iteration is a Promise anti-pattern:

```
function getPriorRows(id) {

  let priorRows = {}, level = 0;

  const getNext = id => fetch(`/api/org/${id}`).then(result => {
    priorRows[level++] = result
    if (result.parentID) {
      return getNext(result.parentID));
    } else {
      return priorRows;
    }
  });

  return getNext(id);
}
```

Either way, the advantage of wrapping the state like this is that you could now have multiple calls to `getPriorRows` proceeding in parallel without interfering with each other.

**EDIT** second code edited to fix a copy&paste error with the recursion - you must call the inner function recursively, not the outer one.